# What would be the best interpretation of my loss function plot?

Tags: loss-functions, overfitting, validation

[image: Loss Function]

I am predicting the results of football games. I trained a 100 cycles. The code is available [here](https://github.com/BorutFlis/predictor/blob/master/soccer_predictor.ipynb).

My interpretation is that the validation loss is at its is lowest already in the start, it only gets slightly larger afterwards. Hence, I assume additional training over-fits the training set and the patterns observed cannot be generalized on the validation set. Also there is quite a lot of up and down variability.

I use Cross-Entropy Loss Function and learning rate =0.0001. There are three categories in the class variable win, draw, loss.

Comment: Pretty much, doesn't seem to be improving, at least with the current settings.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe sharing more info would help: what learning algorithm are you using? What is the type of your response and regressors? Tuning parameters? etc

Comment: I added some description. You can check my notebook as well.